# Understanding feature importance for collinear features with tree-based models

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, multicollinearity, importance, shapley-value

I'm trying to understand how collinearity affects feature importance for tree-based models.

My understanding is that tree-based models naturally overcome multicollinearity for the purposes of prediction, but there seems to be conflicting information about how this affects feature importance calculations.

In my particular case I am working with a gradient boosting machine (LightGBM) on a classification task. I have features that I know are correlated, and am using SHAP for feature importance. The results seem to show the collinear features being ranked as equally important, so I just want to make sure that I am not missing anything, since I've heard that collinear features can mess with feature importance calculation.

Thank you!

---

Relevant prior reading:

Permutation-based importance has limitations:  https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-9-307
https://www.mdpi.com/2079-9292/9/5/761/htm

It looks like SHAP assumes independence:
[Are SHAP values potentially misleading when predictors are highly correlated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535624/are-shap-values-potentially-misleading-when-predictors-are-highly-correlated)

SHAP also seems to have a setting for when feature independence can't be assumed:
https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1098

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated, and +1 for then interesting question! What have you read on this topic?

Comment: I added it to the post, thank you!