# Shapley values for groups of correlated features

Tags: feature-selection, independence, importance, shapley-value

Is there a version of Shapley values that does not assume independence of features, and can be used to interpret importance of clusters of "similar" features (by adding individual feature importances for example)?

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/610428/28500) to a related question. I'm not an expert on this, but it seems to be the type of thing you're looking fo.

Comment: Shapley values are used in a couple of different ways in the statistics and machine learning literature and it is not, in general, the case that Shapley value decomposition assumes that model features are independent (though some implementations do assume they are).  Can you expand on the use case to which you are applying Shapley values?  For instance, is this intended to decompose predicted scores by observation from a predictive algorithm? Or, alternatively, is it intended to determine important features in the model?

Comment: I feel like the important part of this is not so much the feature dependence but the fact that it wants the SHAP value for an entire chunk of variables (which might not be independent of each other) instead of just one variable.

Comment: @jluchman I was hoping to do the latter i.e. use this to get some idea of feature importance or weights for interpreting a blackbox model

Comment: @Dave Yeah I was hoping that since many methods of feature importance such as random forests or boosting assign lower importances to correlated variables that might each be of higher importance (due to, for example, randomly picking one or the other),  there might be a method that allows me to aggregate  feature importances in some way so that I may look at groups of correlated variables together.

Comment: @EdM Thank you! Will check that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method recommended here is based on 'classic' Shapley value decomposition that, as has been noted frequently in the literature, is not scalable as it involves 'removing columns/features' and thus refits $2^f$ different models (where $f$ is the number of features). This method does *not* assume independence of featrues however and, in fact, is very useful for ascribing importance in conditions where features are correlated (this is often noted in the literature on 'Dominance Analysis' - on which the `{domir}` package used below is based).  Shapley values, using the column dropping approach to Shapely values is also quite flexible as it is easy to drop multiple columns simultaneously.

As an example, consider this random forest model implemented in R with the `mtcars` data from the `{datasets}` package.

```
> set.seed(25)
> randomForest::randomForest(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) |> 
+   predict() |> 
+   yardstick::rsq_vec(mtcars$mpg, estimate = _) 
[1] 0.8489851
```

I set the seed to ensure the reproducibility of this result specifically, especially as the model is refit in runs below. It's standard importance metrics are also computed.

```
> set.seed(25)
> randomForest::randomForest(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, importance = TRUE) |>
+   randomForest::importance()
       %IncMSE IncNodePurity
cyl  10.902547     165.83137
disp 12.746522     239.73487
hp   12.443743     193.31249
drat  5.389437      58.19412
wt   13.574631     242.07634
qsec  2.536330      28.38492
vs    4.417597      35.49211
am    3.717252      14.87757
gear  3.698947      19.99795
carb  6.280669      39.68566
```

These metrics suggest *wt* and *disp* are most important (in that order).

The alternative Shapley/dominance-based approach is computed below.

```
> domir::domir(
+   terms(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) |> formula(),
+   \(fml) { 
+     set.seed(25)
+     randomForest::randomForest(fml, data = mtcars) |> 
+       predict() |> 
+       yardstick::rsq_vec(mtcars$mpg, estimate = _) 
+   },
+   .cdl = FALSE, .cpt = FALSE
+ )
Overall Value:      0.8489851 

General Dominance Values:
     General Dominance Standardized Ranks
cyl         0.12199217   0.14369177     4
disp        0.17183115   0.20239595     1
hp          0.14207064   0.16734174     3
drat        0.02690479   0.03169053    10
wt          0.15773333   0.18579046     2
qsec        0.03852428   0.04537686     9
vs          0.05023545   0.05917118     6
am          0.04421375   0.05207835     7
gear        0.03942196   0.04643421     8
carb        0.05605759   0.06602895     5
```

This approach suggests also that *disp* and *hp* are important but in that order and, if interested, the user can ask for `.cdl = TRUE` to see the progression of feature collinearity affects how each feature explains variance in *mpg*. Note that this version of importance results in an exact decomposition of the $R^2$ into components attributable to each feature.  This is only possible when random elements in the model are held constant (i.e., the random forests have the same random seed).

Using the `.set` argument, a user can also group features which includes and drops them all jointly.

```
> domir::domir(
+   terms(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) |> formula(),
+   \(fml) { 
+     set.seed(25)
+     randomForest::randomForest(fml, data = mtcars) |> 
+       predict() |> 
+       yardstick::rsq_vec(mtcars$mpg, estimate = _) 
+   },
+   .set = 
+     list(`grp 1` = ~ cyl + disp + wt, `grp 2` = ~ carb + hp, `grp 3` = ~ gear + am),
+   .cdl = FALSE, .cpt = FALSE
+ )
Overall Value:      0.8489851 

General Dominance Values:
      General Dominance Standardized Ranks
drat         0.05185996   0.06108465     6
qsec         0.05776773   0.06804328     5
vs           0.08047303   0.09478733     4
grp 1        0.33222563   0.39132092     1
grp 2        0.22981961   0.27069922     2
grp 3        0.09683914   0.11406459     3
```

Here, many of the most strongly correlated features are in *grp 1* which results in the most important set of features. Note that grouping the features in this way affects how all the features' importance are computed as it affects the number of sub-models that are estimated and incorporated into the computations.

Again, this approach is much less scale-able than alternative implementations that sample the sub-model space or impose assumptions.  That said, the grouping of features can reduce the sub-model space substantially.  Moreover, features of little interest can be put into the `.all` argument and lumped into a component of the $R^2$ that does not contribute at all to the sub-model space.

Comment: gonna try this out- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See [Relative variable importance/explained variation from a single model fit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626376) for a related discussion where a permutation-based importance measure breaks down with high collinearity but a new linear model projection technique does not.  The new relative explained variation measure applies to any regression model and may possibly apply to machine learning algorithms if a saturated linear model can approximate their outcomes.  This is along the lines of *preconditioning* AKA model approximation.