# Relative variable importance/explained variation from a single model fit

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, nonlinear-regression, importance

I am seeking a measure of relative variable importance or relative explained variation that will apply to all types of linear and nonlinear regression models and that requires only fitting one model.  As an example suppose we have the model y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2 with the last term representing an interaction term.  The model may be of any type including logistic, ordinal, and Cox proportional hazards regression models.  Various importance measures have been developed based on Wald $\chi^2$ statistics, and one can compute a measure of importance of x1 by comparing the 2 degree of freedom Wald statistic for x1 and x1:x2 with the 3 d.f. Wald $\chi^2$ for the complete model.  This is all done using the full model fit.  This will not transport to Bayesian models though.

One simple thought is to compute the linear correlation coefficient between lp1 and lp where lp1 is the portion of the linear predictor that involves x1 (which will have two terms combined into one sum, using two estimated regression coefficients) and lp is the overall model fit's linear predictor $X\hat{\beta}$.  I know that traditional $R^2$-based measures will use two $R^2$: from the large and reduced models and this will handle collinearities appropriately, but I'm seeking measures that work reasonable well from a single model fit.

Does anyone have an idea of how well the corr(lp1, lp) approach will work or have a better idea for estimating relative variable importance from a single model fit?  Measures that operate on the estimated full-model regression coefficients will work in both frequentist and Bayesian settings.

**Update**: Another thing to try.  For a relative explained variation in the response that is due to x1, let $\hat{y}$ be the full model linear predictor $X\hat{\beta}$.  Fit a linear model to the linear predictor: $\hat{y} \sim x1 + x2 + x1:x2$.  The $R^2$ from this fit will be 1.0.  Quantify the relative importance of x1 by the partial $R^2$ that is due to the 2 degrees of freedom involving x1, i.e., omitting the x2 main effect from the contrast.  In a linear model one can compute any needed partial $R^2$ from contrasts without refitting anything.  Are there downsides or strange collinearity issues?

**Update 2**: This second method yields an exactly correct result when the initial model is a linear model, as the relative $R^2$ values from predicting the linear predictor, when multiplied by the $R^2$ in the original fit, give exactly the partial $R^2$ in the original fit.  So I'm pretty happy with method 2.  For nonlinear models it is using the linear model as a bridge to get relative explained variation.

**Update 3**: @Michael M discussed *global surrogate models* below.  This would extend the update in **Update 2** along the following lines:

1. Fit a predictive model using any desired method, including random forests (if the sample size is incredibly large)
2. Predict the predictions from that fit using a fairly saturated linear model, i.e., one that uses regression splines for all continuous predictors and includes all two-way interactions (tensor splines).  If this fit has $R^{2} > 0.9$ we would call it an adequate approximation to the random forest.
3. Use that fitted linear model to decompose explained outcome variation (relative $R^2$) in the random forest in an interpretable way.  In the R `rms` package this decomposition combines any effect with higher-order effects involving that variable, so the partial $R^2$ for a predictor would count its nonlinear and interactive effects.

**Update 4**: I've implemented the new general purpose relative explained variation method.  Explanation and examples are [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/validate#sec-val-rev).  It would be nice to compare its performance with random permutation-based methods.

Comment: Two model-agnostic measures: Permutation importance; SHAP importance (via permutation SHAP or some other agnostic-approximation). They both have their ups and downs, but they require only one model fit.

Comment: The word permutation implies that the one model is fitted multiple times though, right?

Comment: It's actually not. The same model is applied to the data with shuffled feature values. Then the increase in the average loss is measured (or similar). Here a link: https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/feature-importance.html . The method was introduced e.g. by Leo Breiman, curiously, 
to measure feature importance in random forests.

Comment: And here a quite cool paper of Mr. Kruskal: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684310, where he rediscovered Shapley values as fairest variable importance measure in models. But his approach requires refitting the model a zillion times.

Comment: @MichaelM Meaning that if permuting the feature has minimal impact on the predictive performance then that feature probably isn’t very important?

Comment: @Dave: exactly. It also allows to evaluate multiple features together, which is important in some applications. It has also negative sides, as is pointed out (hopefully) in Christoph's book.

Comment: Michael I beg to differ.  Permutation methods require far more than the final model fit.  They may require thousands of fits, and in a Bayesian context where I need to run 4000 iterations already this is not feasible.  It's pretty expensive even in the frequentist context.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Because having permitted features might lead to different modeling decisions, e.g., a stronger or weaker penalty in a ridge regression?

Comment: Yes, or more simply said, permuting features requires processing the raw data again.

Comment: Why aren't Shapley/SHAP values what you want?

Comment: Not at all @FrankHarrell. I might not have explained the approaches very well. But there is **no refitting** involved, even if you might have other such methods in mind. For SHAP, one uses permutation SHAP or KernelSHAP. Again, ***no refit*** is required. (I have implemented all mentioned methods in R.)

Comment: For those like me who are unfamiliar with the approach would you mind briefly outlining the computation steps so I can get a feel for what is involved, keeping in mind that the original fit may take an hour to run?

Comment: One approach would be to run the permuted metrics on a single model then compare the results with the simplest approach, e.g., pearson or spearman correlations. That said, Ursula Grömping has probably written the most exhaustive review in the literature of relative importance metrics, as well as proposing her own R module *relimport*. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313007X188252

Comment: That paper is for the linear model case (ordinal least squares).  For that I'm already happy with partial $R^2$.

Comment: Sorry that should have been _ordinary_ least squares.

Comment: To me, the estimators discussed in her papers are fungible. In other words, the metrics can be adapted to other methods.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is the perfect measure to do so. Still, here are two options from explainable ML ***that do not need to refit***:

### Permutation feature importance

The average loss (or some other meaningful performance measure) is calculated on the reference data, typically the validation data to get rid of model optimism. Then, for each feature, its data column is randomly shuffled and the increase in average loss is calculated. If the increase is small, it means the feature is unimportant. The measure was introduced by Leo Breiman for random forests and then later generalized.

#### The algorithm

Screenshot from our [ETH Zurich lecture](https://lorentzenchr.github.io/responsible_ml_material/xai_2_explaining_models.html#5_Variable_Importance)

($\hat m$ is the fitted model)

[image]

- The process can be repeated a couple of times to get more robust results (and standard errors).
- It also works for feature groups (shuffling multiple feature columns together).
- One can also study relative increases in average loss.
- It's easy to implement. The only annoying thing is to specify the loss.

Major drawback: Especially when features are collinear/dependent, shuffling creates uncommon or even impossible values. So the model is forced to extrapolate, which may lead to strange results.

It can be calculated by R packages {iml}, {DALEX}, {hstats} (my new one dedicated to Friedman's model-agnostic interaction statistics).

With {hstats}:

```r
library(shapviz)  # to get a cool dataset
library(ggplot2)
library(hstats)

head(miami)

fit <- glm(
  SALE_PRC ~ log(LND_SQFOOT) + TOT_LVG_AREA + 
    log(OCEAN_DIST) + log(CNTR_DIST) + factor(structure_quality),
  data = miami,
  family = Gamma(link = "log")
)

summary(fit)

v <- setdiff(all.vars(formula(fit)), "SALE_PRC")

system.time(  # 0.3 seconds - note the type = "response" of `predict()`
  imp <- perm_importance(
    fit, X = miami[v], y = miami$SALE_PRC, loss = "gamma", 
                        type = "response"
  )
)

plot(imp)

# Relative increases instead of absolute ones
rel_imp <- perm_importance(
  fit, X = miami[v], y = miami$SALE_PRC, loss = "gamma", 
         normalize = TRUE, type = "response"
)
plot(rel_imp) + 
  xlab("Rel. increase in average loss")
```

[image]
[image]

Shuffling living area increases the average unit Gamma deviance by almost 300%. (The error bars are created by shuffling four times by default.)

References:

1. Breiman, Leo. 2001. “Random Forests.” Machine Learning 45 (1): 5–32. https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1010933404324.
2. https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/feature-importance.html

### SHAP importance

The other frequently used model-agnostic method is based on SHAP values. The SHAP value of feature $j$ and observation $i$ equals the *fair* additive contribution of the feature to the prediction. Taking the average absolute SHAP value over a set of observations is a very natural measure of importance. A value of 0.2, e.g., means that the features increases or decreases the prediction on average by 0.2.

The problem with SHAP values: While their game theoretic pendants (Shapley value) are perfect in all desireable aspects, their translation to statistics is not. Model-agnostic algorithms are either slow or imprecise, and like with partial dependence plots (and permutation importance), the model needs to be applied on sometimes unnatural/impossible feature combinations.

Comment: Neither of these methods are candidates for solutions because they require far more than the final full model fit.

Comment: I don't think there is a model-agnostic method that does not use (any) data, I am afraid.

Comment: I added a new attempt at the end of the post at the top.

Comment: Isn't the main trade-off with permutation that you need independent data to apply it? Breiman proposed it within the context of bagged observations, where it uses the out-of-bag error to estimate importance. @FrankHarrell didn't specify, but I assume there isn't independent data here...

Comment: Once again let me state that I'm seeking a method that does not require you to repeat any computationally expensive step.  Permuting data or needing a different dataset are examples of computationally prohibitive steps I'm needing to avoid.  When I do this in a Bayesian context I'll already have thousands of sets of $\beta$ values from thousands of posterior draws.  This will allow me to compute uncertainty intervals for whatever relative importance measure I use, thus accounting for parameter estimate uncertainty, which partially also accounts for overfitting.

Comment: Is applying `predict(fit, modified data)` too expensive in your situation?

Comment: @DavidB: As I have stated in the answer, you would usually use validation data for permutation importance. It is, however, not forbidden to use the training data. (A bit like when you calculate any performance measure on the training data, which is what Frank is after, I think.) SHAP methods on the other hand do not use the response. There, it does not matter.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: I added the formula of permutation importance to the explanation. SHAP algorithms are a bit more involved, so I will wait extending that part.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll keep assuming that all these methods are too computationally intense to use in the general case.  But I should have stated that I'm working in the additive space (except for pre-specified interaction terms) where things are easier, e.g., various $R^2$ measures exist.

Comment: Well, it is up to you to try out something new... If the extremely cheap permutation importance algo is already too expensive, then it is good to not have talked too much about SHAP ;-).

Comment: A comment above clarifies some of what I was confused about.  If you permute a variable's rows and recompute predictions that is a very fast step when you save the design matrix at the front end.  I was thinking you had to get new regression coefficients on permuted data.  Thanks.

Comment: For cases in which the structure is set (regression, as opposed to random forests, for example) and only coefficient estimation is at issue, I'll be interested in what those familiar with these variable importance measures used in the machine learning world think about the simpler second option I put at the top of this topic where the variable importance comes from a linear model re-fit to predictions from the nonlinear original model.

Comment: This goes into the direction of "global surrogate models". Fit simple model (linear regression or a single tree) to the model predictions of a black box model and then study the "white box" model instead. Its R-squared is used as an indicator of approximation quality. Regarding our discussion above: I am not so experienced with Bayesian models, so calculating predictions as modes from some posterior distribution might indeed be expensive.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  The Bayesian procedure would be to repeat the variable importance measure calculation 1000 times over 1000 posterior draws of the regression coefficients, get 1000 importance measures for each predictor, and feed those 1000 through a fast algorithm for getting an uncertainty interval for importances.

Comment: I've learned a lot from this discussion.  My current thinking is that random permutation methods are quite general but probably lead to more volatile (higher standard errors) importance estimates.  The _global surrogate model_ @MichaelM spoke about is more appealing to me.  I'll expand upon that thought with an update to the OP.

Comment: I didn’t see it mentioned in the responses (apologies if it was), but the permutation method does not make much sense when you have multicollinearity issues since it requires individually permuting the individual predictor columns (I.e., you’ll likely end up with invalid or unlikely data instances like age=3 and height=6 ft, which is essentially extrapolating).

Comment: @bgreenwell  I mentioned it somewhere here, fully agree. I'd even claim that there is no model agnostic method that can deal with collinearity *without refitting* models.

Answer (score 2):

> **Update 4**: I've implemented the new general purpose relative explained variation method. Explanation and examples are here. It would be nice to compare its performance with random permutation-based methods.

To perform the comparison, I first wrote an R function which computes the random permutation-based relative explained variation (REV) metric. This metric quantifies the impact of shuffling a given predictor on model performance, indexed by the model linear predictor ($X\hat{\beta}$).

```r
rexVar_perm <- function (object, nperm = 20) {
  #' compute permutation-based REV from ols and orm objects  
  
  # extract predictor indices from anova.rms(fit) (great suggestion by Prof Harrell)
  # codes taken from rex() inner function of rexVar()  https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/blob/master/R/rexVar.r
  a <- anova(object)
  pind <- attributes(a)$which
  rm <- c("TOTAL NONLINEAR","TOTAL NONLINEAR + INTERACTION",
          "TOTAL INTERACTION","TOTAL", 
          " Nonlinear"," All Interactions", "ERROR",
          " f(A,B) vs. Af(B) + Bg(A)")
  rn <- rownames(a)
  rm <- c(rm, rn[substring(rn, 2, 10) == "Nonlinear"])
  pind <- pind[rn %nin% rm]
  names(pind) <- sub('  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)', '', names(pind), fixed=TRUE)
  
  #' write a nested loop to compute rev of individual predictors and 
  #  repeat process nperm times
  
  lp_full <- predict(object)
  rx <- matrix(NA, nrow=nperm, ncol=length(pind), 
               dimnames=list(NULL, names(pind)))
  
  for (i in names(pind)) {
    for(j in 1:nperm){
      X     <- object$x
  draws <- object$coefficients
      set.seed(j)  # ensure reproducibility 
      srows <- sample(seq_len(nrow(X)))
      X[, pind[[i]]]   <- X[srows, pind[[i]], drop = FALSE] 
      lp_shuffle <- matxv(X, draws)
      rev <- 1- cor(lp_shuffle, lp_full)
      rm(X)
      rx[j, i] <- round(rev,3)
      
    }
  }
  
  return(apply(rx, 2, mean))
  
}
```

Next, I used the `MASS` package to simulate datasets with different collinearities and compute the corresponding general purpose-based and random permutation-based REVs. Focussing on the simplest case (and to make things easy for myself), each dataset has 2 predictors (v1 and v2) and a continuous outcome (y).

```r
library(rms)
library(here)
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
source("rexVar.R")  ## https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/blob/master/R/rexVar.r
source("rexVar_perm.R")

# write function to generate dataframe with correlated predictors
sim_cdata <- function(cor_val, n = 100){
  Sigma <- matrix(c(1, cor_val, cor_val, 1), ncol = 2)
  predictors <- mvrnorm(n, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = Sigma)
  
  # assume predictors share equal predictive power 
  y <- 1 * predictors[, 1] + 1 * predictors[, 2] + 
           rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  data <- data.frame(v1 = predictors[, 1], v2 = predictors[, 2], y)
  return(data)
}
```

As it turns out and as cautioned by @Michael M and @bgreenwell, when the predictors are strongly collinear (correlation > 0.80 in our example), the random permutation-based REV results become somewhat erratic. In contrast, the general purpose-based REV values decline steadily with increasing collinearity, reflecting the diminishing incremental predictive value that a given predictor has over its (correlated) counterpart.

@Michael M and @bgreenwell, given that datasets with collinearities are not a rarity in biomedical research, could you advise on alternative variable importance measures that are used in the machine learning world?

```r
gen_rev <- function (data){
  mod_ols <- ols(y ~ v1 + v2, x=T, data = data)
  perm_rev <-   rexVar_perm(mod_ols, nperm = 500)
  rexVar_rev <- rexVar(mod_ols, data = data)
  r <- c(perm_rev, rexVar_rev)
  return(r)
  }

cor_seq <- seq(0, 0.98, by = 0.02)

rx <- matrix(NA, nrow= length(cor_seq), 
             ncol=5, 
             dimnames=list(NULL, 
                           c("cor_val", "v1_perm","v2_perm", 
                             "v1_rexvar", "v2_rexvar")))
s <- 0 
for(i in cor_seq){
  s <- s + 1
  mydata <- sim_cdata(cor_val = i, n = 500)
  rx[s,] <- c(i, gen_rev(mydata))
}  
dt <- data.table (rx)
long_dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = "cor_val", variable.name = "variable")
long_dt[, c("variable", "method") := tstrsplit(variable, "_", 
            fixed = TRUE)]

ggplot(long_dt, aes(x = cor_val, y = value, color = method)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ variable) +
  labs(
    x = "Correlation between predictors",
    y = "REV value",
    title = "Comparison between rexVar and permutation algorithm"
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 13)
```

[image]