# Permutation Feature Importance with an ensemble of models

Tags: machine-learning, importance

I would like to use Permutation Feature Importance (PFI) with a set of different models coming from a bootstrap procedure.

I was looking at the [algorithm here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html#outline-of-the-permutation-importance-algorithm) and was wondering how it can be used when the model is not just one.

$Algorithm$

- Compute the reference score $s$ of the model $m$ on data $D$ (for instance the accuracy for a classifier or the $R^2$ for a regressor).
- For each feature $j$ (column of $D$):

  - For each repetition $k$ in $1,...,K$:

    - Randomly shuffle column $j$ of dataset $D$ to generate a corrupted version of the data named $\tilde{D}_{k,j}$.
    - Compute the score $s_{k,j}$ of model $m$ on corrupted data $\tilde{D}_{k,j}$.
  - Compute importance $i_j$ for feature $f_j$ defined as $i_j = s-\frac{1}{K}\sum{_{k=1}^{K}s_{k,j}}$

I can think of a simple way which is taking the mean score per feature from every model but I am not sure if this can be done or if there are other ways to do that.

Comment: Taking the mean PFI of all the models is probably the easiest option.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if there was any paper or book where they did this before, but it makes sense.

Comment: As shown at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626376 this permutation measure does not perform correctly when there is strong multicollinearity.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this and I am performing variable selection and avoid multicollinearity before this step.